# How to get the newest record without using limit in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL script to find out the newest record, but it fails to get the incorrect result. I am giving the SQL script below:

```
SELECT  
    adjust_after,
    spu_code,
    sku_code,
    store_id,
  create_time
FROM
    goods_store_stock_update_record 
WHERE
    is_del = 0 
    AND create_time >= DATE '2021-05-26'  
    AND create_time <= DATE '2021-05-27'
    AND store_id = '18cc1cc715774d0196d17420c5104c15'
    AND sku_code = 'SKUH201900001202050004'  HAVING MAX(create_time)
```

There is a result without Having max(create_time):

```
"adjust_after"  "spu_code"  "sku_code"  "store_id"  "create_time"
"8" "SPH201900001202050001" "SKUH201900001202050004"    "18cc1cc715774d0196d17420c5104c15"  "26/5/2021 11:29:20"
"7" "SPH201900001202050001" "SKUH201900001202050004"    "18cc1cc715774d0196d17420c5104c15"  "26/5/2021 11:35:14"
```

But, when I am trying to query the create_time that was the newest:2021-05-26 11:35:14 record using having max(create_time). Unfortunately, It returns the incorrect record below:

```
8   SPH201900001202050001   SKUH201900001202050004  18cc1cc715774d0196d17420c5104c15    2021-05-26 11:29:20
```

Therefore, in this situation, how can I correct the querying script without using order by create_time and limit one.
Best regards. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `LIMIT`? It seems the straight-forward approach.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: My MYSQL version is 5.7

Comment: `HAVING MAX(create_time)` causes the next: 1) all data array is treated as one group 2) maximal  `create_time` value is found and checked that it is not NULL or zero 3) some (indefinite, random) row from the group is returned

Comment: *My MYSQL version is 5.7* Get `MAX(create_time)` in subquery and use as a filter in outer query. But if there is more than 1 row with this time then all of them will be returned.

Comment: I don’t want to use Limit because  I want to get the newest record for each group, as I know how to get the newest without limit I can find out a way to solve how to get each group's newest record.

Comment: On a side note: Be aware that `create_time <= DATE '2021-05-27'` is `create_time <= TIMESTAMP '2021-05-27 00:00:00'`, i.e. including only midnight of the last day. You probably want `create_time < DATE '2021-05-27'` or `create_time < DATE '2021-05-28'`

Comment: Group? Which group are you talking about?

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is very old by the way. Any reason why you are not using MySQL 8?

Comment: One more thing: I suggest you `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` This will help you write proper queries that contain aggregation (such as your `MAX(create_time)`).

Answer (score 1):

There are two main mistakes in your query.

First, `HAVING` wants a boolean expression, just like `WHERE`. `MAX(create_time)` is not a boolean, but a datetime. What MySQL does here is convert the datetime to a number (maybe the internal representation of that datetime) and the number to a boolean (where 0 = false and everything else = true). So, that expression will result in true for about every row.

Second, `MAX(create_time)` is an aggregation. Without a `GROUP BY`clause this results in a single row. `adjust_after` etc. however, are not aggregated. This should result in a syntax error, but MySQL applies `ANY_VALUE` instead. This means you are telling MySQL, to give you one of the `adjust_after` that it finds, one of the `spu_code`, etc., all arbitrarily picked.

The straight-forward solution would be `ORDER BY create_time LIMIT 1`, which you don't want for reasons unknown to us.

Another solution is

```
SELECT 
  adjust_after,
  spu_code,
  sku_code,
  store_id,
  create_time
FROM goods_store_stock_update_record 
WHERE is_del = 0 
  AND store_id = '18cc1cc715774d0196d17420c5104c15'
  AND sku_code = 'SKUH201900001202050004' HAVING MAX(create_time)
  AND create_time =
  (
    SELECT MAX(create_time)
    FROM goods_store_stock_update_record 
    WHERE is_del = 0 
      AND create_time >= DATE '2021-05-26' 
      AND create_time <= DATE '2021-05-27'
      AND store_id = '18cc1cc715774d0196d17420c5104c15'
      AND sku_code = 'SKUH201900001202050004'
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,I understand the having function